# What is the punishment for a person who is not Hindu?

Tags: teaching

I want to know that if a person is non hindu then what is the punishment for him after dying as a non hindu.

Comment: None, as Hinduisms never been a religion in vedas etc, so there is nothing mentioned about non hindus.

Comment: No Punishment. "What you sow is what you reap"- Principle of  Karma.  Lord is verily one and people call Him by different names. The various forms of Gods such as Vishnu, Shiva, Devi are Gods to all 7 billion people.

Comment: So it means a person can be a non Hindu without any risk after death.

Comment: @SuhailAKhtar Haha. Where did you hear that non-Hindus will be punished after death? I think some fanatic might have misguided you. There's no reason to get punished and Karma has its formula and religion doesn't play a role in this. Life is all about cause and effect of your actions, which is nothing but **KARMA**.

Comment: I heard a monk once say that Hinduism is a way of life, not a religion. Rest easy.

Comment: no punishment. If they lead a good life, they will sow good karma. If they try to realize God through another religion, even better. A more interesting question is: The Hindu religion is the only religion that tells man that the goal of life is to see - realize- God in this very lifetime. What happens to a man born into the Hindu religion and wastes his life by not taking heed to realize God????

Comment: Well nothing much will happen if you are good throughout your life, the only thing we can gurantee(one exception if you somehow get Bramhajnana) that wouldn't happen to you is that you wont be able to attain moksha the highest position held by an individual atman after death (soul frees itself from cycle of birth and death). As such there is no punishment because we have also tolerated schools like Charvaka alongside Thestic Vedanta School.'

Answer (score 1):

There are some wrong ways mere Yes or No for your question can be taken. If I say the answer as Yes there is a so and so punishment (though there is none), I would be presenting you Hindu religion in a mis-interpreted and wrong way. Since the answer is a No, still it can go wrong. So No punishment also means

1. It does not give anyone even a Hindu to leave all the duties ordained on him/her by his religion.
2. Just to escape the duties of one's religion or for any of one's own selfish motives one cannot change religion.

There is no punishment. Before giving references, Let me clarify you certain things.

**1. Hinduism**

Hinduism is a name that was given very recently to this religion. But its original name was always Sanatana Dharma which means that it flowed perennially from time immemorial. In olden days and in yugas this is the only dharma that existed. This fact is always evident by the teachings of the scriptures and acharyas. Rama or Krishna did not establish Hinduism, they were the followers of Sanatana Dharma. Just to state one fact among them,  In [Valmiki's Ramayanam Kishkindha Kanda Sarga 18](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/kish/sarga18/kishkindha_18_frame.htm), Lord Rama in response to Vali's questions says

> **This earth** with its mountains, woods, and forests, even along with the
> authority to condone or condemn the animals, birds, and humans on it
> **belongs to Ikshvakus**. He who is virtue-souled, truth-abiding,
> plain-speaking, and the knower of the import of probity, pleasures,
> and prosperity, and the one who is concerned in controlling or
> condoning his subjects, **that Bharata is the ruler of earth**. In whom
> both scrupulousness and benignancy are there, truthfulness is firmed
> up, and valour as evinced by scriptures is evident, and he who is the
> knower of time and place is the king, namely Bharata. Holding his
> virtuous decree desiring to keep up the continuum of righteousness, we
> and some other kings are wayfaring this earth in its entirety.

Also in the lecture on [Evolution as per Vishnu Purana](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UlfETa7RK0I), HH Tridandi Ramanuja Chinna Jeeyar Swami mentions that Puranas state that the whole earth was once in the shape of quadrilateral and after Sagara's sons digged it, all divided as different parts (moderns call it continental drift). After that **world looked like a rabbit eating a bush**. That is the reason we say in pravara **chatuh sagara paryantam**, if land as a single mass is quadrilateral then on all four sides it has four oceans.

This proves that the whole earth was under the kingship of a one king (Lord Rama) in Treta Yuga itself. Later with advent of Kali Yuga, due to the decline of Sanatana Dharma in every other part of the world, the new religions or to state in [the words of Swami Dayanada Saraswati](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YnNfDRsRcTA) "the neo-religions" had come up. That is why they are called mataas, one which originated from a person's mind. But what we call Hinduism today was always there from time immemorial. We did not evolve from apes, but all were the children of God call it brahma, prajapati, vishnu, Siva, Lalita or any name.

**2. Punishment for not being a Hindu**
Since no other mataas existed until recent times, it might be hard to find scriptural evidences for the punishment of not being a Hindu. So, instead I would like to state in the words of Acharyas present in Sanatana Dharma.

1. **Jagadguru Shankaracharya Abhinava Vidya Tirtha Mahaswami of Sringeri Sarada Peetham**, a well known **jivanmukta** once said "**Each person should follow his own religion. One should not claim their path to be the only path or abuse other paths**". Also I quote up [a conversation](http://www.kamakotimandali.com/sringeri/vilasa_4.html) which happened with him which would be helpful.

> Some young men had the Darshan of Sri Mahasannidhanam and said,
> 'People belonging to other religions are trying to convert Hindus to
> other religions by offering jobs, money and other materialistic
> comforts. This is greatly harming the Hindu society. Please take some
> action to prevent these unlawful religious conversions.
>
> Mahasannidhanam replied, '**What do you mean by religion?** We have to
> first understand this clearly. The only way to know this is through
> the Shastras. **Religion i.e. Mata is related to 'mati' or intellect.
> The caste of a person i.e. 'jAti' is related to 'janana' or birth.**
> Take the example of a certain breed of a cow. Can we simply change its
> qualities to resemble another breed by changing its name? **What is now
> called Hindu dharma is actually Sanatana Vaidika dharma. That whose
> beginning is not known is referred to as 'Sanatana'. If you take the
> example of most other religions today, it has been started by a
> particular person and has a date from which it came to existence. Our
> Sanatana dharma has neither such known beginning nor has it been
> established by a single person. One should clearly understand the
> difference between jAti and mati. How to change one's mata? By
> advising an atheist, his mata can be changed and he can be made a
> theist. But jAti can never be changed. We think, 'he was a Hindu, he
> now became a Christian'. But in reality that is not possible. A person
> who leaves his own dharma for various reasons like material comforts
> is called 'bhraShTa'.** You told me that various groups of organizations
> have been converting Hindus to other religions. This fact was already
> understood by our ancients and they have classified victims of
> conversion into four different categories.
>
> **Our dharma imposes certain rules and restrictions.** It advises people
> to eat Satvic food and give up Tamasic foods like onions, garlic, meat
> and fish. It asks us to stay away from liquor and tobacco. It asks us
> to keep fasts for Ekadashi, Shivaratri etc. It bans eating anywhere,
> anything and with anyone. **Some people think, 'God has given us tongue
> solely to enjoy the taste of various foods. Why should one follow
> rules of eating only certain things and with certain people? Such
> people who do not want to follow rules and want to enjoy 'eating' get
> converted to other religions which have no disciplinary rules.**
>
> **Rules related to marriage are very strict in our dharma**. People fro
> the same Gotra are not allowed to mary as this amounts to a brother
> marrying his sister. Also, one is not allowed to marry a lady elder to
> him in age. One is also required to see the lineage of the
> bride's/groom's family. **Some get converted to other religions, which
> have no such rules, to enjoy marriage with anyone desired.**
>
> **The Dharma classifies the society into Shudra, Vaishya, Kshatriya and
> Brahmana, and rules and duties increase exponentially from Shudras to
> Brahmanas.** A Brahmana has to follow special rules like waking up
> before sunrise, offering Arghya exactly during sunrise,
> Sandhyavandana, worship of Gods, Brahma Yajna, Vaishwadeva, Agnihotra,
> Aupasana etc. **There are other religions which proclaim, 'You don't
> have to do anything. All your sins will be forgiven. Whatever sins you
> commit, if you pray that day, your sins will be forgiven. People, who
> want to perform no Karmas, get attracted to religions as these where
> there are no assigned duties.**
>
> **A person who fails to follow his own dharma is called 'bhraShTa'. In
> olden days, such a person would be kept away from the society. When he
> realized his mistake, repented for the same and purified himself, the
> society would accept him back.** If a religion says, 'You don't have to
> repent for your mistake and do anything to correct yourself. Just tell
> us what you did and we will assure you forgiveness. A bhraShTa would
> naturally choose the easier way out and get converted.
>
> **I am also aware that the poor and needy get converted for the sake of
> money and employment. But this trend of converting people from
> Sanatana Vaidika dharma to other religions has been present from time
> immemorial.** But have not we emerged victorious every time? All we need
> to do is to educate our people about the greatness of Sanatana Vaidika
> dharma. Once people realize the timeless worth of our culture,
> conversions will recede drastically.
>
> **In our society, we have the Varnashrama dharma, which is incorrectly
> projected as casteism, racism and what not? But one should observe
> that other religions also have various divisions within them. Once a
> Muslim priest belonging to the Sunni community told me, 'All those
> belonging to Sunni community go to heaven and those belonging to Shia
> community go to hell. I was speaking to a Roman Catholic priest one
> day and he said, 'My driver for today was a protestant. I could not
> even drink water during my journey today. How could I drink water in
> front of him? Won't it get contaminated? I belong to the orthodox
> church. I am quoting these to highlight the fact that differences are
> there in all societies and this is not just restricted to the Hindu
> society.**
>
> **Our dharma has imposed some rules called 'samAna dharma' for all the
> four Varnas: non-violence, truth, not desiring other's property,
> cleanliness of mind, words and body, control over the organs of action
> and sense. Now don't you think the other religions also speak of these
> qualities? Any community following these will find peace and
> fulfillment'.**

2. **His Holiness Sri Sri Sri Tridandi Ramanuja Chinna Jeeyar Swami [says](http://chinnajeeyar.guru/chinnajeeyar/about-chinna-jeeyar-swamiji/) "SERVE ALL BEINGS AS SERVICE TO GOD. WORSHIP YOUR OWN RESPECT ALL”**
3. **Ramakrishna Paramahamsa** said "I have practised all religions—Hinduism, Islam, Christianity—and I have also followed the paths of the different Hindu sects. **I have found that it is the same God toward whom all are directing their steps, though along different paths.** I see men quarrelling in the name of religion—Hindus, Mohammedans, Brahmos, Vaishnavas, and the rest. But they never reflect that He who is called Krishna is also called Siva, and bears the name of the Primal Energy, Jesus, and Allah as well."
4. **Swami Dayananda Saraswati** explains "**[Conversion is Violence](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A4sEMVJuDCY)**"
5. Many other great gurus like Shiridi Sai Baba were against this. (I might add the reference later)

Hope this helps you.
P.S: It is not my intention to hurt anyone's feelings, just stating the facts. Every religion should live in harmony with others.

Answer (score 0):

No Punishment--If you follow the principles laid in your religion then no punishment will be there also. As Shirdi Sai said Ram and Rahim are one. There is no difference in them. Punishment is based on one's Karma whether if it is balanced, decreased or increased.

Comment: Please answer with sources. Else your answers may get downvotes or altogether get removed.

Comment: @The Destroyer---Change the answer to comment--If we cite source also you  are not accepting. Life History of sai baba you can find this.

Comment: i have no privileges to convert  it to comment. Moderators can do that.